# Don't generate map click events when marker clicked in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

So, I have a leaflet map...

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([35.772219, -78.675272], 17);
map.on('click', function(e) {alert('map click!')});
```

and I add a marker...

```
var marker = L.circleMarker([35.772219, -78.675272]);
marker.on('click', function(e) {alert('marker click!')});
marker.addTo(map);
```

If I click on the marker, both the marker and map click events fire, but I only want the click event for the marker... Is there any way to accomplish this? I can't seem to find one in the docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`L.DomEvent.stopPropagation`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#domevent-stoppropagation) should do the trick:

> Stop the given event from propagation to parent elements. Used inside
>   the listener functions:

```
marker.on('click', function(e) {
    L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
    console.log('marker click!')
});
```

And a demo (one circle cancels its event and not the other)

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([35.772219, -78.675272], 10);
map.on('click', function(e) {console.log('map click!')});


var marker = L.circleMarker([35.772219, -78.68]);
marker.on('click', function(e) {
    L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
     console.log('marker click!')
});
marker.addTo(map);

marker = L.circleMarker([35.772219, -78.63], {fillColor: 'red'});
marker.on('click', function(e) {
     console.log('marker click with map click')
});
marker.addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 100px"></div>
```

Comment: OK, this definitely works. Any idea why `e.originalEvent.stopPropagation(e);` doesn't work? According to the docs, `e.originalEvent` should be the `DomEvent` in question...

Comment: It's probably not the DOM event that gets propagated to the map but an event managed by Leaflet, which would explain why you have to use a Leaflet utility to cancel it.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to add a e.preventDefault();  and e.stopPropagation() in the function of your marker click? Like so:

```
marker.on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); alert('marker click!');});
```

Comment: Would need to use `e.originalEvent.stopPropagation();` to get the actual event instead of the Leaflet wrapper, but this still does not work. Could be propagating from map to marker?

Comment: Hmm, that would be weird, with leaflet your markers should be above the map (tiles speaking) so the marker click is the first event triggered. Do you have some img on yours markers or a customed style on them?

Comment: Try with L.DomEvent.stopPropagation() instead, at least thats why their docs says.
https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#domevent

Answer (score 0):

use `event.stopPropagation()`, to stop event bubbling to the parent. See [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

```js
document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('Listening parent');
});

document.querySelector('.child').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Listening child');
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  parent
  <div class="child">
    child
  </div>
</div>
```